# UDP Chat Server using message structs

Tags: c, networking, server, udp, chat

I've been trying to set up a simple UDP Chat server to learn how to make my own chat room , for starters I am just getting the hang of running a UDP server with clients who share the same IP / port as the server. The clients send data in the form of a struct.
There is 3 possibilities that a server should expect , a new client joining , and it recognizes that by matching the command JOIN , or a client quitting by matching the command QUIT , or a message by matching neither of those...

those commands are stored in the struct that the client is sending in the form , of (ID , COMMAND , Domain/Port )..
unless it's a message then it would be (ID , Domain/Port , Message). Which i've handled in my code .

the client 100% works as it was provided to me as a source, but I cannot use it since it's executable, so the problem is from my server . I made a debugging tool to check what's going wrong, it seems like when a client joins and I am acknowledging back to that client that I've accepted him , the client never receives back the acknowledgmenet , and that is because i am not formatting it correctly.
It should be something like  `Received: <1 JOIN loki>`   then `Sent: <1 JOIN loki>` where the 3 variables with the brackets are the struct parts.. but it does not store the 2nd string which is the domain/port part correctly... so when I run the debugging tool I get `Received: <1 JOIN>` , `SENT <1 JOIN>`.
So why would it be doing that like I parse the struct into my buffer struct then send it . How come it's not capturing the domain part correctly?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LOCAL_PORT 2317
#define MAX_LEN 255

struct message {

    int   cid;                    /* Connection ID */

    char  str1[MAX_LEN];         /* JOIN, QUIT, or client-domain-name */

    char  str2[MAX_LEN];        /* user-string or client-domain-name */

};



int rcv_cid;

int rc,sd;

struct message my_msg, rcv_msg;

char rcv_str1[MAX_LEN];

char rcv_str2[MAX_LEN];




int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    struct sockaddr_in  servAddr;
     int servLen = sizeof(servAddr);
    int IDlist [] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ;
    int i=0;  int port;
    /* Socket Creation */
    if(argc < 3){
        printf("usage : ./chatServer <port#> <debug_option:0 or 1>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM , 0);
    if(sd<0) {
        printf("%s , cannot open socket \n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

     /* bind argv[1] server port */
     servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    /* bind argv[1] which is what the user provides */
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

       rc= bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr , sizeof (servAddr));
if(rc <0){
    printf("%s: cannot bind port number %d \n", argv[0], port);
    exit (1);
}
printf("%s: waiting for data on port UDP %d \n", argv[0], port);

while(1) {
    /* grab incoming request */
    rc = recvfrom(sd, &rcv_msg, MAX_LEN, 0,   (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, &servLen);
   printf(" %s \n" , rcv_msg.str2);
    if(atoi(argv[2]) == 1){
       printf("DEBUG: Receiving <%d %s %s>\n",rcv_msg.cid,rcv_msg.str1,rcv_msg.str2);
   }
    if(strcmp(rcv_msg.str1,"join") == 0 ) {

        for( i =1; i< 11 ; i ++){
            if(IDlist[i] ==  rcv_msg.cid ){
                rcv_msg.cid = i;
                IDlist[i] = rcv_msg.cid;
                break;}
        }



    /*         for(j = 0, j < 10 ; j ++){                     */
    /*          if(IDlist[j]  !=  IDlist [i] ){              */

    my_msg.cid = i;
    strcpy(my_msg.str1, "JOIN");
    strcpy(my_msg.str2, rcv_msg.str2);    

    if(atoi(argv[2]) == 1){
            printf("DEBUG: Sending <%d %s %s>\n",my_msg.cid,my_msg.str1,my_msg.str2);
                                }

    rc = sendto(sd, &my_msg, sizeof(my_msg)+1, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,
            sizeof(servAddr));
    /* compose a temp struct , then send it to each ID on the list except the one we just added */
    }


if(strcmp(rcv_msg.str1,"QUIT") == 0 ) {

    for( i=0;i<10 ; i++){
        if(rcv_msg.cid == IDlist[i])
            IDlist [i] = 0;
    }
    my_msg.cid =  rcv_msg.cid;
    strcpy(my_msg.str1, "QUIT");
    strcpy(my_msg.str2, rcv_msg.str2);    /*my name Nodname contains domain and port number built into C library */

if(atoi(argv[2]) == 1){
                    printf("DEBUG: Sending <%d %s %s>\n",my_msg.cid,my_msg.str1,my_msg.str2);
                                                        }


    rc = sendto(sd, &my_msg, sizeof(my_msg)+1, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,
             sizeof(servAddr));
 }
 else {

my_msg.cid =  rcv_msg.cid;
strcpy(my_msg.str1,  rcv_msg.str1);
strcpy(my_msg.str2, rcv_msg.str2);    /*my name Nodname contains domain and port number built into C library */

  if(atoi(argv[2]) == 1){
                printf("DEBUG: Sending <%d %s %s>\n",my_msg.cid,my_msg.str1,my_msg.str2);
                                                    }


rc = sendto(sd, &my_msg, sizeof(my_msg)+1, 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,
        sizeof(servAddr));

                   }

           }

        return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only allow the system to read at most `MAX_LEN` bytes:

```
rc = recvfrom(sd, &rcv_msg, MAX_LEN, 0, 
    (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, &servLen
);
```

but `rcv_msg` is more than twice that size (it's `2 * MAX_LEN + sizeof(int)`). Correct would have been:

```
rc = recvfrom(sd, &rcv_msg, sizeof(rcv_msg), 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, &servLen
);
```

Also `servLen` must have type `socklen_t` and not `int`; it is not guaranteed that both types are equal or interchangeable.

And this code is wrong as well:

```
rc = sendto(sd, &my_msg, sizeof(my_msg)+1, 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)
);
```

`my_msg` is exactly `sizeof(my_msg)` big, so why do you tell the system to send `sizeof(my_msg)+1` bytes? What is that `+1` doing there? This one byte is past the end of the struct, it doesn't belong to the struct, this memory may be padding or belongs already to a different variable. You are not supposed to read that byte after the struct, this may even crash your program if you are unlucky.

Then you need to be careful with capitalization. In your code, the commands are always upper case ("JOIN"), but this code line compares against a lower case string:

```
 if(strcmp(rcv_msg.str1,"join") == 0 ) {
```

`strcmp` is case-sensitive, `strcmp("JOIN", "join")` will not return `0`!

And have you considered that the problem may not be the receiver not receiving the message correctly but the sender not sending the message correctly? I only have your receiver code, I don't have any sender code. You say the client works as you got it in source code, but that doesn't mean that it works correctly or that is sends data the way you believe it does. Without seeing how the client sends out data, I cannot really tell you the exact cause of the problem and I also have no test case to test the server code.

If I fix all the problems indicating above and make the server send a test message to itself, that works just fine on my system and you can even test that code directly online and there it works correct as well, see here:

http://rextester.com/MSH79937

Comment: @MohammedAl-Huneidi Then the client doesn't send data that looks the way think it does. I found two more mistakes in your code pointed out above, but w/o any client code, I cannot build a test case and w/o a test case, I cannot tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Huneidi Also added a test case where you can test the fixed code directly online it just works correctly, so if you still have issues, you didn't correctly add all the fixes I pointed out or the error is in the client.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying in your response my mistakes . The problem is that the client is an executable . Thus I don't have access to its source unless I decompile it. However when I run the client with the debugging Tool activated , it shows that the struct gets sent like this <0 JOIN Loki> where Loki is the domain name . it's garaunteed that the struct follows the format I mentioned above within the client . My friend used the same executable code that I'm using and his program works fine and he claims his struct is exactly like mine , which is driving me crazy .

Comment: @MohammedAl-Huneidi Are you on a Linux/UNIX/MacOS system by any chance? Then you can probably `tcpdump` the message: Something like `tcpdump -i INTF -X udp port 2317` should work, where INTF it the name of the interface to monitor (e.g. eth0 or eth1 on Linux, en0 or en1 on MacOS, etc.) This will capture all UDP packets from/to port 2317 arriving at the selected interface and dump them as a hex dump to terminal. Hit CTRL+C to stop that command again. Edit your question and add the hexdump of such a packet, so we can look what it really looks like.